# Factory method pattern with multiple constructors having various sets of arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, factory

I am trying to make a factory function that will be able to create objects derived from a base class using different constructors based on the given parameters. With some help from other posts here I have been able to make an example that works for a constructor that takes no parameters, but I cannot find a solution for multiple constructors.

I have the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;

class BaseObject {
public:
    BaseObject(){cout<<"BaseObject def constructor\n";};
    BaseObject(int type){cout<<"BaseObject non-def constructor\n";}
    virtual ~BaseObject() = default;
    virtual string name() = 0;
};

class Object1 : public BaseObject
{
public:
    Object1(){cout<<"Object1 def constructor\n";};
    Object1(int type){cout<<"Object1 non-def constructor\n";}
    virtual string name() override
    {
        return "I am Object1";
    } 
};

class Object2 : public BaseObject
{
public:
    Object2(){cout<<"Object2 def constructor\n";};
    Object2(int type){cout<<"Object2 non-def constructor\n";}
    virtual string name() override
    {
        return "I am Object2";
    } 
};

struct Factory {
public:
    typedef std::map<std::string, std::function<std::unique_ptr<BaseObject>()>> FactoryMap;
    
    template<class T>
    static void register_type(const std::string & name) {
        getFactoryMap()[name] = [](){ return std::make_unique<T>(); };
    }

    static std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> get_object(const std::string name) {
        return getFactoryMap()[name]();
    }
    
    static std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> get_object(const std::string name, int type) {
        return getFactoryMap()[name](type);
    }
    
    // use a singleton to prevent SIOF
    static FactoryMap& getFactoryMap() {
        static FactoryMap map;
        return map;
    }        
};


int main()
{
    Factory::register_type<Object1>("Object1");
    Factory::register_type<Object2>("Object2");

    // make Object1 using default constructor
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o1 = Factory::get_object("Object1");

    // make Object2 using non-default constructor
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o2 = Factory::get_object("Object2", 1);

    std::cout << o1->name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << o2->name() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "exit" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Both `Object1` and `Object2` have two constructors (it is simplified, in practice the one with the parameter will get some saved data) and `Factory` has two versions of `get_object()` each with the name of the object to be created and the corresponding additional parameters.

The problem with the second `get_object`

```
    static std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> get_object(const std::string name, int type) {
        return getFactoryMap()[name](type);
    }
```

is that the call to the constructor inside passes `type` parameter, but the type of the function (as defined by `typedef FactoryMap`) has no parameters (`std::function<std::unique_ptr<BaseObject>()>`).

I explored variadic templates but was not able to figure out how it should be done. One of the helpful post was [this one](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/114578/simple-factory-retrieving-object-by-name), unforunately it does not have a full working code example.

Comment: Are you always going to just have two kinds of constuctors? If so you could just use two different factory maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspired by the [answer by @numzero](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74406217), I finally adopted a solution that uses less magic/templates and thus it looks more elegant to me. This solution works for constructors having fields of complex types, on the other hand it is limited by a requirement of all `BaseObject` descendants to have the same set of constructors (but that was the idea from the start):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;


class BaseObject {
public:
    virtual ~BaseObject() = default;
    virtual string name() {
        return "I am BaseObject";
    }
};

class Object1 : public BaseObject
{
public:
    Object1(const int i){cout<<"Object1 int constructor\n";}
    Object1(const std::string s){cout<<"Object1 string constructor\n";}
    Object1(const std::vector<double> params){cout<<"Object1 vector constructor\n";}
    virtual string name() override
    {
        return "I am Object1";
    } 
};

class Object2 : public BaseObject
{
public:
    Object2(const int i){cout<<"Object2 int constructor\n";}
    Object2(const std::string s){cout<<"Object2 string constructor\n";}
    Object2(const std::vector<double> params){cout<<"Object2 vector constructor\n";}
    virtual string name() override
    {
        return "I am Object2";
    } 
};

using constructor1_t = std::function<std::unique_ptr<BaseObject>(const int)>;
using constructor2_t = std::function<std::unique_ptr<BaseObject>(const std::string s)>;
using constructor3_t = std::function<std::unique_ptr<BaseObject>(const std::vector<double>)>;
using constructors_t = std::tuple<constructor1_t, constructor2_t, constructor3_t>;
using constructors_map_t = std::unordered_map<std::string, constructors_t>;

template <class T>
std::function<constructors_t()> object_constructors = [](){
    return constructors_t{
        [](const int i){return std::make_unique<T>(i); },
        [](const std::string s){return std::make_unique<T>(s); },
        [](const std::vector<double> v){return std::make_unique<T>(v); }
    };
};

constructors_map_t constructors_map = {
    {"Object1", object_constructors<Object1>()},
    {"Object2", object_constructors<Object2>()}
};

int main()
{
    int i = 12;
    std::string s = "abc";
    std::vector<double> v(4, 0.0);
    
    auto c1 = constructors_map["Object1"];
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o1 = std::get<0>(c1)(i);
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o2 = std::get<1>(c1)(s);
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o3 = std::get<2>(c1)(v);
    std::cout << o1->name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << o2->name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << o3->name() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "----" << std::endl;
    
    auto c2 = constructors_map["Object2"];
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o4 = std::get<0>(c2)(i);
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o5 = std::get<1>(c2)(s);
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o6 = std::get<2>(c2)(v);
    std::cout << o4->name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << o5->name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << o6->name() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is really hard in the general case as C++ lacks reflection. It can be solved however, in the assumption that the set of available constructors is fixed for a given factory. That is if you’re fine with defining your factory like `using Factory = BaseFactory<BaseObject, void(), void(int)>;` it is possible albeit requires <s>black magic</s> more templates. (`using X = Y` is the new, sane form of `typedef Y X`, and `ret(args)` is a function type [not a pointer but function itself; used like `void`, only in pointers and templates]). For example:

```cpp
template <typename Base, typename Constructor>
struct Subfactory;

template <typename Base, typename... Args>
struct Subfactory<Base, void(Args...)> {
    using constructor_type = std::unique_ptr<Base>(Args&&...);

    template <typename Type>
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> construct(Args&&...args) {
        return std::make_unique<Type>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

template <typename Base, typename... Constructors>
struct BaseFactory {
public:

    using ConstructorList = std::tuple<typename Subfactory<Base, Constructors>::constructor_type *...>;

    inline static std::map<std::string, ConstructorList> types;

    template<class T>
    static void register_type(const std::string & name) {
        types[name] = ConstructorList{Subfactory<Base, Constructors>::template construct<T>...};
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> make_object(const std::string name, Args&&...args) {
        const ConstructorList &type = types[name];
        auto constructor = std::get<std::unique_ptr<Base>(*)(Args&&...)>(type);
        return constructor(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

using Factory = BaseFactory<BaseObject, void(), void(int)>;

int main()
{
    Factory::register_type<Object1>("Object1");
    Factory::register_type<Object2>("Object2");

    // make Object1 using default constructor
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o1 = Factory::make_object("Object1");

    // make Object2 using non-default constructor
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o2 = Factory::make_object("Object2", 1);

    std::cout << o1->name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << o2->name() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "exit" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

**Explanation**

```cpp
template <typename Base, typename Constructor>
struct Subfactory;

template <typename Base, typename... Args>
struct Subfactory<Base, void(Args...)> {
    using constructor_type = std::unique_ptr<Base>(Args&&...);

    template <typename Type>
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> construct(Args&&...args) {
        return std::make_unique<Type>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};
```

This is a helper to unpack a function type. Specifically, the partial specialization matches all usages of the form `Subfactory<any type, void(anything here)>`, filling `Args...` with that “anything”.

Now, the factory itself.

```cpp
template <typename Base, typename... Constructors>
struct BaseFactory {
```

Here, `Constructors...` is for the list of constructor signatures

```cpp
    using ConstructorList = std::tuple<typename Subfactory<Base, Constructors>::constructor_type *...>;
```

For each element `C` of `Constructors...`, this extracts the type `Subfactory<Base, C>::constructor_type *`, and defines `ConstructorList` as a tuple of all these types.

```cpp
    inline static std::map<std::string, ConstructorList> types;
```

A nice, C++17-only (but note that `make_unique` is C++17 too) replacement for `getFactoryMap`. Optional, your `getFactoryMap` is equally usable.

```cpp
    template<class T>
    static void register_type(const std::string & name) {
        types[name] = ConstructorList{Subfactory<Base, Constructors>::template construct<T>...};
```

This instantiates `Subfactory<Base, C>::construct<T>` for each `C` from `Constructors...` and makes `ConstructorList` passing (pointers to) these functions as arguments.

```cpp
    template <typename... Args>
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> make_object(const std::string name, Args&&...args) {
        const ConstructorList &type = types[name];
        auto constructor = std::get<std::unique_ptr<Base>(*)(Args&&...)>(type);
        return constructor(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
```

This gets the “type info” (constructor list) from the map, then gets appropriate constructor [wrapper] from the tuple (based on the received arguments), and calls it.

```cpp
using Factory = BaseFactory<BaseObject, void(), void(int)>;
```

Here, `Factory` is defined as a factory of `BaseObject` supporting constructors with no arguments and with single `int` argument.

Note that this solution is not perfect. It requires good match of arguments given to the factory with the arguments it supports; no overloading resolution takes place. Supporting that is likely possible but requires more complicated tricks.

**Update:** here is a similar solution but with proper overload resolution:

```cpp
/// A wrapper over single constructor of a single type.
/// @param Base is the common type
/// @param Constructor is a function type denoting the constructor signature. It must have the form `void(constructor arguments)`
template <typename Base, typename Constructor>
struct Subfactory;

/// The only specialization of @c Subfactory
template <typename Base, typename... Args>
struct Subfactory<Base, void(Args...)> {
    /// The pointer to the constructor wrapper.
    std::unique_ptr<Base> (*constructor)(Args&&...args);

    /// The outer constructor wrapper. Unlike @c constructor which is a variable, this one is a function thus can participate in overload resolution.
    std::unique_ptr<Base> construct(Args&&...args) {
        return constructor(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    /// A factory factory. Returns an instance able to construct an object of type @p Type, but only with a constructor accepting @p Args as arguments.
    template <typename Type>
    static Subfactory metafactory() {
        /// The constructor wrapper (written as a lambda for compactness)
        return {[](Args&&...args) -> std::unique_ptr<Base> {
            return std::make_unique<Type>(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }};
    }
};

/// The generic factory.
/// @param Base is the common type. Objects are returned as pointers to that type
/// @param Constructors are function types denoting the constructor signatures. Each must have the form `void(constructor arguments)`, and they must all be distinct
template <typename Base, typename... Constructors>
struct BaseFactory {
public:
    /// A wrapper on constructor list of a single type.
    /// It inherits one @c Subfactory for each constructor signature from @c Constructors.
    /// Could also hold additional information, if necessary.
    struct TypeInfo: public Subfactory<Base, Constructors>...
    {
        /// Another factory factory. Returns an instance able to construct an object of type @p Type with any supported constructor.
        template <typename Type>
        static TypeInfo metafactory() {
            return TypeInfo{
                Subfactory<Base, Constructors>::template metafactory<Type>()...
            };
        }

        /// Brings *all* constructor wrappers in the scope so that @c construct names them all, as overloaded functions.
        using Subfactory<Base, Constructors>::construct...;
    };

    inline static std::map<std::string, TypeInfo> types;

    template<class Type>
    static void register_type(const std::string & name) {
        types[name] = TypeInfo::template metafactory<Type>();
    }

    template <typename... Args>
    static std::unique_ptr<Base> make_object(const std::string name, Args&&...args) {
        return types[name].construct(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }
};

/// A factory of @c BaseObject subclasses, supporting constructors taking nothing or a single int.
using Factory = BaseFactory<BaseObject, void(), void(int)>;

int main()
{
    Factory::register_type<Object1>("Object1");
    Factory::register_type<Object2>("Object2");

    // make Object1 using default constructor
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o1 = Factory::make_object("Object1");

    // make Object2 using non-default constructor
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o2 = Factory::make_object("Object2", 1);

    // make Object2 using overload resolution of a non-default constructor
    std::unique_ptr<BaseObject> o3 = Factory::make_object("Object2", 'c');

    std::cout << o1->name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << o2->name() << std::endl;
    std::cout << o3->name() << std::endl;

    std::cout << "exit" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Instead of storing function pointers in a tuple, a special type, `TypeInfo`, is used. One pointer is stored in each its base class, all of which are `Subfactory` but with different template arguments. Each `Subfactory` defines a `construct` function with appropriate arguments, and `TypeInfo` inherits them all and makes them all visible, thus subject to overload resolution like original constructors themselves.

Comment: Fantastic! The best thing is that this solution not only works, but it is a very general one. The `BaseFactory` is a template that is independent of the original base class (`BaseObject`) and so it may be used for different purposes with different base classes.

Comment: If the constructor has a non-scalar parameter, e.g. `Object1::Object1(const std::vector<double>)`, then the factory template has a problem: `cannot bind rvalue reference of type ‘std::vector<double>&&’ to lvalue of type ‘std::vector<double>’`. Is the method limited to scalar types only?